# Is there a way to export a custom process in Azure Boards?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm currently working on defining a customized process based out of the default Agile process template.

If possible, I'd like to get a template of this so I can store it in our git repository to track any changes.

Read a few articles and most of the stuff I've found were for TFS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?view=azure-devops

Am I correct that this isn't currently possible with Azure Boards?

EDIT: Seems it's possible to extract my Processes and Layouts via the REST API but there doesn't seem to be an Add/Update function for Layouts(which is what seems to define the actual Work Item Type)

```
...
"id": "Agile.Bug.Bug",
      "inherited": true,
      "overridden": true,
      "label": "Details",
      "pageType": "custom",
      "locked": false,
      "visible": true,
      "isContribution": false,
      "sections": [
        {
          "id": "Section1",
          "groups": [
            {
              "id": "Agile.Bug.Bug.Repro Steps.WideGroup",
              "inherited": true,
              "label": "Repro Steps",
              "isContribution": false,
              "visible": true,
              "controls": [
                {
                  "id": "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
                  "inherited": true,
                  "label": "Repro Steps",
                  "controlType": "HtmlFieldControl",
                  "readOnly": false,
                  "watermark": "",
                  "metadata": "",
                  "visible": true,
                  "isContribution": false
                }
              ]
            },
...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/layout/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

Comment: Hi, how are things going now? Does your puzzle can solved with the below explanation?

Comment: Yeah that helped explain things. I did find this on the Microsoft Github page but haven't given it a try. https://github.com/microsoft/process-migrator

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Azure DevOps Services (cloud version) and you have created an Inherited process template from one of the out-of-the-box process templates (Agile, Scrum, CMMI or Basic), then you could use the [Process Migrator tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/process-migrator) to Export/Import that process template into another Azure DevOps Services organization.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to export a custom process in Azure Boards?

You are right, custom process only supported in TFS(Azure Devops Server) not VSTS(Azure Devops Service).

Since TFS is a **local** server wihch built on a SQL Server back end, its process templates  need be customized with code. Oppositely, VSTS is a **cloud** service and its process templates can be updated **automatically** on a regular basis because of its hosted by cloud. So, in VSTS, user must need inherited the process template first, and then customize part of them. But this customizable range in VSTS is smaller than in TFS. You can check the doc which show the difference between VSTS and TFS:
[Process customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/about-azure-devops-services-tfs?view=azure-devops#process-customization).

In addition, customize process with code not only support TFS, but also some orgs which **migrated from TFS to VSTS**. In the org which migrated from TFS to VSTS, the feature of customize process with code retained. So, in these orgs, you will see that they both has the feature which support on cloud and local:

[image]

And also, you can customize the process which in VSTS with REST API. But as I said previously, this has limitation. You just can modify it basic on and limit by the default process configuration.

So, as your question:

- If you are using VSTS, and your org is not migrated from TFS, you
  could not export and import process in Boards.
- If you are using TFS, you can directly export the process, customize
  it and then import into your org to apply it in Boards. Because you could not enjoy the advantage of update process template automatically by cloud.
- If your org is migrated from TFS, and now its hosting in VSTS, you
  can enjoy both previous two customize way.